# What is the physical interpretation of the monogamy of entanglement?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

From a mathematical point of view, it is clear to me that if two particles A and B are maximally entangled, then nor A nor B can be maximally entangled with a third particle C. Now, my question is more about the physical interpretation to it. From what I know, two particles get entangled in the moment they get in contact with one another (I'm quite new to the whole subject, so I'm sorry for being so "vague" :D). So, if a third particle C gets in contact with, say, A, why can't they get entangled if there is a previous maximal entanglement between A and B?

Comment: C can certainly become entangled with A. But a side effect of that will be a lessening of the entanglement between A and B.

Comment: Oh, I see. But then, from an entropy point of view, what happens exactly? Like, let's say I have 2 qubits so that $S(\rho_A | \rho_B) = -1$. Now, a third particle gets into play and gets in contact with $A$, so we have $S(\rho_A | \rho_C) < 0$. Isn't this now contradicting the monogamy of entanglement inequality $S(\rho_A | \rho_B) + S(\rho_A | \rho_C) \geq 0$?

Comment: You must've missed something because the initial state of $S(\rho_A | \rho_B) = -1$ and $S(\rho_A | \rho_C) = 0$ also contradicts it.

Comment: I'm not saying that happened in my calculations. I'm just trying to figure out what happens when a third particle gets into play while the other two are already entangled. If $C$ gets in contact with $A$, you are saying that it can get entangled with it. Does this mean that $B$ gets completely unentangled with $A$ after $C$ gets in contact with $A$?

Comment: Not necessarily. A state with some entanglement between all three could also be produced.

Comment: But then I don't understand the monogamy of entanglement. We are saying that if two particles are entangled, then neither one of them can be entangled with a third. I mean, I know that you can produce some entangled state between 3 particles like $(|000>+|111>)/\sqrt{2}$, but then the entanglement is over the 3 particles all together. So, if $C$ gets in contact with $A$ maximally entangled with $B$, does this create a tripartite entanglement? I don't understand what happens to the subsystems then.

Comment: If two particles are *maximally* entangled then neither one of them can *at the same time* be entangled with a third. But as the state evolves in time due to some interaction, all bets are off. A state where all pairs are entangled (but none maximally so) is fine.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you! And from an entropy point of view then, what does this mean? Both $S(\rho_A | \rho_B)$ and $S(\rho_A | \rho_C)$ are negative? This is still unclear to me :/